# Angular Material=> Mat-chip- Autocomplete(input) on selecting dropdown through space key

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

How to populate `mat-chip`  `onkeypress(spacebar)` when we select `mat-option` by going on option through arrow key and pressing space key(32).

However, it is working fine when we select dropdownmenu by going to option through arrowkey and then pressing enter key(keycode- 13) but not working on similarly on space key(keycode -32).

Here, is stackblitz link:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytk8qk-feaqaw?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html

```
1) How to add select dropdown option by going through
  arrowkey(not mouse) and populating selected option using spacebar(keycode- 32).

2)How to remove option from dropdown that is already populated or used.

3)Show dropdown only when user enters some charcter in input text else show 
  class="info"` text only in dropdown, when no input text is there and no 
 option in dropdown matches enter charcters in input.

Note:- The user can create chips by typing in input and then press ENTER or SPACE key (separator key) for creating chips.
```

### chip.component.ts

```
export class ChipsAutocompleteExample {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER,SPACE, COMMA];
  fruitCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredFruits: Observable<string[]>;
  fruits: string[] = ['Lemon'];
  allFruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];

  @ViewChild('fruitInput') fruitInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('auto') matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  constructor() {
    this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit) : this.allFruits.slice()));
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    // Add fruit only when MatAutocomplete is not open
    // To make sure this does not conflict with OptionSelected Event
    if (!this.matAutocomplete.isOpen) {
      const input = event.input;
      const value = event.value;

      // Add our fruit
      if ((value || '').trim()) {
        this.fruits.push(value.trim());
      }

      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }

      this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
    }
  }

  remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.allFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that if the list component is focused, space key works the same as enter. On the stackblitz you provided, I tried inspecting one of the elements of the list, then returned to the list, pressed space key and it was selected. Maybe knowing this may help you implement what you're looking for.

Comment: Its not working. You don't have to use mouse to open dropdown. When input is focus just use arrow key to select a particular option and click space key to select that option. However, enter key is working.

Comment: Have you reviewed this? space doesn't seem to be an option for autocomplete https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#keyboard-interaction

Comment: Thanks, Keyboard interaction

DOWN_ARROW: Next option becomes active.UP_ARROW: Previous option becomes active.ENTER: Select currently active item.

Comment: But, it can also be selected using space key. That is requirement

Comment: @Marshal, I am trying to handle that space key event and get the corresponding active option and perform action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How to add select dropdown option by going through
>     arrowkey(not mouse) and populating selected option using spacebar(keycode- 32).

1. Add properties to hold the selected fruit and the currently displayed fruits (filtered ones):

   `selectedFruit = -1;
    displayedFruits = [];`
2. After view init, subscribe to changes on keyManager to get the selected option and to changes on filtered fruits to get the filtered list and store it on displayedFruits :

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.matAutocomplete._keyManager.change.subscribe((index) => {
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.selectedFruit = index;
    }
  })
  this.filteredFruits.subscribe((filteredFruits) => {
    this.displayedFruits = filteredFruits;
  });
}
```

3. On add method, include an else clause to include the fruit and reset selectedFruit to -1:

```js
add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
   // Add fruit only when MatAutocomplete is not open
   // To make sure this does not conflict with OptionSelected Event
   if (!this.matAutocomplete.isOpen) {
     // ...
   } else {
     if (this.selectedFruit >= 0) {
       this.fruits.push(this.displayedFruits[this.selectedFruit])
       this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
       this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
     } else if (this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value !== '' && this.displayedFruits.length === 0) {
       this.fruits.push(this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value)
       this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
       this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
     }
   }
   this.selectedFruit = -1;
}
```

> 2)How to remove option from dropdown that is already populated or used.

Enhance the filter to also check for already used fruit:

```js
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
   const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
   return this.allFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0 && !this.fruits.find( existingFruit => existingFruit === fruit ));
}
```

> 3)Show dropdown only when user enters some charcter in input text else show 
>     class="info"` text only in dropdown, when no input text is there and no 
>    option in dropdown matches enter charcters in input.

If I got it right, you may do this:

1. Bind to input focus event to show autocomplete when input is focused

```js
<input
placeholder="New fruit..."
#fruitInput
(focus)="matAutocomplete.showPanel = true"
[formControl]="fruitCtrl"
[matAutocomplete]="auto"
[matChipInputFor]="chipList"
[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
[matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
(matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
```

2. Modify your autocomplete template to show an extra class="info" option when no text is entered or no value matches:

```js
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
  <mat-option class="info" *ngIf="displayedFruits.length === 0 || fruitInput.value === ''" disabled>Test</mat-option>
  <ng-container *ngIf="fruitInput.value !== ''">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of displayedFruits" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytk8qk-otbhco)

Comment: Thanks, Please suggest some solution for 2 and 3 part.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr I've updated the answer and stackblitz with points 2 and 3.

Comment: There is a bug in your implementation, user is unable to create chips by just writing in input and then pressing ENTER or space Key.(Please have a look at my stackblitz), if user does not want dropdown options.

Comment: Did a little change on the add method.

Comment: Its not working. Its adding chip even when input is empty onpressing of space key and enter key.

Comment: It shall be okay now. I understand it already addresses all the issues, but of course there may be some fine tunings.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to figure out issue in your solution is whenever I am trying to select dropdown option using mouse click, it is not selecting the whole word.One functionality is affecting other.

Comment: This entire functionality is very tricky, but did some changes, tested a little bit and it seems that it finally correctly addresses all possibilities.